# Question about theory of machines (kinematic diagrams)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, kinematics, machine-design

Can I draw this part of kinematic diagram in this way, knowing that bolded W is a point of interest. so is my drawing true also? (my lines are in red and black(no[image]t bolded black))?

Comment: are you asking if you can draw the red line freehand, or if you need to use a ruler?

Comment: if the only forces are vertical you can estimate the device by leaving out vertical dimensions.  But if there are any other forces, including moments, you need to draw it according to actual.

Comment: @Jastola. I'm asking if my drawing is a true drawing instead the one drawn already (not about ruler it's about the way of drawing(location of joint and triangle)

Comment: @tiger guy so at the end is my alternate drawing true?

Answer (score 0):

Don't look correct to me. Are you trying to draw the displacement diagram?

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly . since L5 is directly connected to horizontal link 6 I connected them directly but what the book did is what you can see taking an inverse triangle of mine. Once you've drawn a line between link 5 and JOINT D it may look like another joint .

Comment: Unless something is hidden, the book is wrong, because the bar L6 is an integral piece without breaking at D, and the small plate D is welded to L6, so while L5 can push and rotate about the pin at D, it can't bend L6 to form the kink as shown. Or, is L6 a much weaker material?

Comment: not at all . same material . Thank you my brother for your help